# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "fetched_row"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am quite new to SQL, so here is the query I am trying to run

```
WITH fetched_row AS (SELECT * FROM sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature LIMIT 1)


        UPDATE sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature
                SET is_processed=true
        FROM (SELECT * FROM sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature WHERE (st_dwithin(location_modeled, fetched_row.location_modeled, 20, TRUE) AND
                sign_type=fetched_row.sign_type AND
                ts!=fetched_row.ts) ) as candidate_signs
        WHERE candidate_signs.id = sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature.id;
```

I have also tried

```
WITH fetched_row AS (SELECT * FROM sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature WHERE (is_processed=false OR is_processed=NULL) LIMIT 1),
             candidate_signs AS (SELECT * FROM sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature WHERE (st_dwithin(location_modeled, fetched_row.location_modeled, 20, TRUE) AND
                sign_type=fetched_row.sign_type AND
                ts!=fetched_row.ts))
        UPDATE sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature
                SET is_processed=true
        FROM candidate_signs
        WHERE candidate_signs.id = sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature.id;
```

Still I am getting the error

```
[42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "fetched_row" Position: 272
```

I do understand, that error is probably somewhere here

```
SELECT * FROM sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature WHERE (st_dwithin(location_modeled, fetched_row.location_modeled, 20, TRUE) AND
                sign_type=fetched_row.sign_type AND
                ts!=fetched_row.ts)
```

But still no luck in debugging it and getting it to work. I think I am missing something quite obvious.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results really help.  Non-functional queries are often not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `fetched_row` in the `FROM`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature,
     fetched_row
WHERE (st_dwithin(location_modeled, fetched_row.location_modeled, 20, TRUE) AND
                sign_type=fetched_row.sign_type AND
                ts!=fetched_row.ts)
```

It would make sense to join on the distance condition (same result, but cleaner):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sdmk_stereo_unfiltered_road_feature
 JOIN fetched_row ON st_dwithin(location_modeled, fetched_row.location_modeled, 20, TRUE)
WHERE  sign_type=fetched_row.sign_type 
  AND ts!=fetched_row.ts
```

Comment: Solved all the problems. As I said, that it should be quite obvious, thank you for pointing at it :)